# _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1366, "Incorrect integer value: '%s' for column 'ID' at row 1")

Tags: python, csv, mysql-python

I am trying to insert my data from .csv to Mysql database using python script.

python script which i used

```
import csv
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost',user='root',passwd='password',db='EfficientBazzar')
cursor = db.cursor()

csv_data = csv.reader(file('products.csv'))
for row in csv_data:
    cursor.execute('INSERT INTO vendor_price_list(ID,Vendor,productname,productcode,unit,weight,price)' 'VALUES("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s")')

db.commit()
cursor.close()
print "Done"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're forgetting to insert the row data into your update query.

Replace:

```
'VALUES("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s")'
```

with:

```
'VALUES("%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s")' % tuple(row)
```

Comment: Glad I could help! Please do accept the answer then ;P.

Comment: Hi, could you explain what you are inserting?

Answer (score 0):

Actually even better, consider parameterizing query:

```
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO vendor_price_list(ID,Vendor,productname,productcode,unit,weight,price)' + \
               ' VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)', row)
```

Even faster is a bulk command straight from csv with MySQL's [`LOAD DATA INFILE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html) (assuming server instance settings allow it):

```
cursor.execute("LOAD DATA INFILE '/path/to/products.csv'" + \
               " INTO TABLE vendor_price_list" + \
               " FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '\"'" + \
               " LINES TERMINATED BY '\n' IGNORE 1 ROWS")
```